# RC Circuit question

Tags: transistors

Am newbie to electronics. Interested to know just how this blinking light circuit works[image]

Comment: Yes, it blinks. The circuit is called the light house circuit. It is one of the circuits in the electric learning kit that I am using. My understanding is that when the capacitor is being charged the base of the transistor is charged briefly allowing the transistor to turn on. The transistor switches off when capacitor full. I am not sure why the capacitor then discharges

Comment: If the transistor Is off and therefore no current flow through it why does the capacitor discharge? Why then is there a difference between voltage source ( battery) and Capacitor voltage to cause the capacitor to discharge

Answer (score 2):

When the circuit is first switched on, the capacitor is discharged. Current flows through the transformer to the capacitor.

The capacitor current turns the transistor on, which allows more current to flow through the LED. This current also flows through the bottom half of the transformer winding, inducing a corresponding voltage on the upper half. This additional voltage charges the capacitor to a voltage *higher* than the supply voltage.

When the capacitor is charged, current stops flowing through it, which causes the transistor to start to switch off.

When the transistor (and LED) cuts off, the voltage at the upper end of the capacitor drops to the supply voltage. This also drives the base voltage of the transistor *below* ground, making sure it cuts off completely.

The capacitor now discharges slowly through the 1M resistor, until the voltage at the bottom end is high enough to turn the transistor on again, starting the cycle over.

The result is a series of short flashes from the LED, resembling the flashing of a lighthouse seen from a distance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It makes perfect sense.

Comment: Just to clarify for me why does the capacitor continue to discharge when it has reached battery voltage?

Comment: The resistor is pulling the bottom of the capacitor up, while the top of the capacitor is basically fixed at the supply voltage. This continues until current begins to flow through the B-E junction of the transistor.

Comment: Now that is the sticky point for me. So the resistor draws current from the bottom end of the capacitor but the top of the capacitor remains essentially unchanged. Then what happens?

Comment: So is the junction above the capacitor not a 4-way junction, but rather just two wires crossing over each other but not in contact? That part of the schematic is very confusing. It looks like the top winding of the transformer is shorted.

Comment: Just 2 wires crossing over each other, no junction. Sorry, should have explained the asterisk

Comment: Also like to add that the supply side of the coil is 300mH the upper half being 150mH as is the bottom. The kit I am using has no separate coils so uses the input coil of the transformer as a stand alone coil

Comment: I’m always amazed by the ingenuity behind “simple” circuits like this :^)

Comment: Yes. Somethings that look simple at first blush are quite profound on closer inspection

Comment: David Tweed stated that the bottom half of the coil induced a current in the top half that charges the capacitor to a value higher than the battery voltage. I am not quite clear on how that happens. Hopefully Mr Tweed can explain this to me. Thank you

Comment: The coil functions as an (auto)transformer. A key feature of a transformer is that windings with an equal number of turns (equal inductance) have the same voltage across them. In this case, if the center tap is held at a constant voltage and one end is pulled to a lower voltage, then the other end rises by a corresponding amount.

Comment: Wow! Never would have figured that out on my own. Most appreciate the explanation.